# Adding two edittext values together and displaying result in another edittext

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the value of two EditText values added together. I used another example, in which I could get the result of subtracting one EditText value from another and displaying that result in an EditText. However, I can't seem to figure out how to add two together and get a result. The result should be computed automatically when the first two EditText fields have values in them.

The code I have is as follows:

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
{
    eAmountReceived = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amountReceived);
    eTotalCost = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.orderTotal);
    eTip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tip);
    eMileage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mileage);
    eGrandTotal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.grandTotal);

    sAmountReceived = eAmountReceived.getText().toString();
    sTotalCost = eTotalCost.getText().toString();
    sMileage = eMileage.getText().toString();
    sTip = eTip.getText().toString();

    try
    {
        dAmountReceived = Double.parseDouble(sAmountReceived);
        dTotalCost = Double.parseDouble(sTotalCost);
        dSubtract = dAmountReceived - dTotalCost;
        dMileage = Double.parseDouble(sMileage);
        dGrandTotal = dSubtract + dMileage;


        dAdd = dTotalCost + dSubtract;


    } catch (NumberFormatException e){}

    sTip = String.valueOf(dSubtract);

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    sTip = df.format(dSubtract);

    eTip.setText(sTip);

    sGrandTotal = String.valueOf(dGrandTotal);

    sGrandTotal = df.format(dGrandTotal);

    eGrandTotal.setText(sGrandTotal);
}
```

"sTip" is the result of subtracting totalCost from AmountReceived. So when the user types in the total cost of a transaction and then types in the amount that they received from the customer, it would automatically compute their tip from the customer.

I'm trying to do the inverse of this, but everything I've tried results in an error, or just doesn't work. I would like it to be where if the user types in the totalCost and the tip, it displays the AmountReceived. Thank you in advance to anyone that can point me in the right direction!

EDIT: Updated code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    eAmountReceived = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amountReceived);
    eTotalCost = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.orderTotal);
    eTip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tip);
    eMileage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mileage);
    eGrandTotal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.grandTotal);

    eAmountReceived.addTextChangedListener(this);
    //eTotalCost.addTextChangedListener(this);
    eTip.addTextChangedListener(this);
    //eMileage.addTextChangedListener(this);
    //eGrandTotal.addTextChangedListener(this);

    eTip.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int count, int after){}

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int before, int count)
        {
            if(eTip.isFocused() && isSet(eAmountReceived) && isSet(eTotalCost))
            {
                updateSubtract();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){}
    });

    eAmountReceived.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int count, int after){}

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int before, int count)
        {
            if(eAmountReceived.isFocused() && isSet(eTotalCost) && isSet(eTip))
            {
                updateAdd();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){}
    });
}

private void updateAdd()
{
    double dTotalCost = Double.valueOf(eTotalCost.getText().toString());
    double dTip = Double.valueOf(eTip.getText().toString());
    eAmountReceived.setText(String.valueOf(dTotalCost + dTip));
}

private void updateSubtract()
{
    double dAmountReceived = Double.valueOf(eAmountReceived.getText().toString());
    double dTotalCost = Double.valueOf(eTotalCost.getText().toString());
    eTip.setText(String.valueOf(dAmountReceived - dTotalCost));
}

private boolean isSet(EditText editText)
{
    return !editText.getText().toString().matches("");
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    updateAdd();
    updateSubtract();
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every edittext add text change listener. For example, listener for dTotalCost or dSubtract would look like this:

```
dTotalCost.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

@Override    
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
 int count, int after) {
}

@Override    
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
 int before, int count) {
  if(s.length() != 0)
   dAdd = dTotalCost + dSubtract;
  }
});
```

**EDIT: add interface TextWatcherand add it to the editexts**

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements TextWatcher {
/* initializations
 ********** 
 */

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

eAmountReceived = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amountReceived);
eTotalCost = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.orderTotal);
eTip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tip);
eMileage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mileage);
eGrandTotal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.grandTotal);

eAmountReceived.addTextChangedListener(this);
eTotalCost.addTextChangedListener(this);
eTip.addTextChangedListener(this);
eMileage.addTextChangedListener(this);
eGrandTotal.addTextChangedListener(this); 

// put listener only to the fields you need

}

// implement interface methods

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

// THIS IS CALLED EVERY TIME CHARACTER IS WRITTEN
// HERE YOU CAN CALL YOUR METHODS FOR CALCULATIONS  i.e. afterTextChanged

afterTextChangedCalculations();

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

// This method is called to notify you that, somewhere within s, the text has been changed.

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Sorry I've been working all day. If I implement this into my code, would it go in my onCreate method? I've tried using it, but it only seems to work when I set the textChangedListener to my totalCost editText. Also, if I put this code into my onCreate method and leave the rest of my code as-is, the app crashes, or just doesn't work right. I guess since I'm using dSubtract in another calculation already?

Comment: First of all move your EditText initialization to onCreate because initializing it this way is wrong.  Every edittext should be in onCreate. Then implement textListener and add it to every editext. Check my edit in the answer above. That should be the solution you're looking for. Just be sure for which field you really want the listener.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've updated my code with add and subtract methods, which I thought would do the trick but now I'm getting a NullPointerException and my app crashes. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I will accept your answer for pointing me in the right direction, but I just don't understand where I'm getting the exception.

Comment: Thanks for the incoming answer accept. In this case where you can't determine the exact spot of NPE you should debug value which is NPE right from the start where it isn't or it shouldn't be null.

Comment: The app crashes instantly upon clicking the button from the main screen to go to this window. The only thing I can think of is that all of my editText fields are null at the beginning and I'm performing calculations on null values or something so it won't even allow me to launch the activity. Maybe it's something as simple as saying....if (some value) != null...do the calculations. Anyway, thank you for your help. It's a good start in the right direction.